# media query failing to load correct css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I just read the article http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design
and am trying to test out a few ideas. I would like to load a different css file depending on the size of the device that is browsing my site.

I have the following code:

```
 <link href="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/css/rh-mobile.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-device-width: 1280px)" href="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/css/rh.css" />
```

Inside both the rh and rh-mobile css files, I have the following class:

```
.hero-unit {
  background: url("../img/ipod5.jpg");
  height: 4em;
  width: 15em;    
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
     -moz-border-radius: 4px;
          border-radius: 4px;
}
```

The only thing that's different between the two is the image that's being loaded. 
the mobile css loads a file called ipod5.jpg and the desktop version loads another file.

While testing my site in firefox, I'm noticing that neither css is being loaded.  The only one that is being loaded is bootstrap.css

Can you tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Is your screen width greater than `480px` and perhaps `1280px`? If so, it will not be loading because you are "over" your `max-device-width` for the css to be engaged.

Comment: right, if you are testing in the browser, do `max-width`

Comment: by changing it from max-device-width to max-width - its working.  can you explain the difference?

Comment: `max-width` is based off the actual current display size of the browser window, whereas `max-device-width` is based on the maximum amount the device can actually display. So if one's screen _resolution_ is `1280`, that is the `max-device-width`, even though the actual browser window _display_ size may be 50% of that screen (`640`), which is what `max-width` is tracking.

Comment: why load different css files , when things can be handled with media queries within one css files and serve the same purpose you are tryng to achieve by different files .Any insight on that ?

Comment: Shail, one reason i create separate css files is because if I upgrade bootstrap, for example, I have to redo all my changes.  If i keep my code separated, it's easier to upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation ScottS. Can you create your comments as an answer so that I can accept / close this question?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap, why don't you just use responsive bootstrap?
Btw base url should be written like this `<?php echo base_url("assets/css/bootstrap.css")?>`